# Applying numeric validations for non required fields

Tags: laravel

I want to apply numeric validation for a form input field. I'm using a separate request class for this. i tried `somtimes nullable` But they didn't give me the answer. Even if i didn't apply `required` validation
the field doesn't let me it blank. I show some quesions related to this problem. But they didn't give an answer. i am using laravel 5.7.28

The rule i am using is below

```
    {

        $rules = [
        'transaction_rate_type' => ['required'],
        'discount_in_percentage' => ['numeric', 'between:0,99.99'],
        'account_type' => ['required'],

        ];

        return $rules;
    }


migration is

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('billing_programmes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('transaction_rate_type');
            $table->decimal('discount_in_percentage');
            $table->integer('account_type');
            $table->uuid('created_by');
            $table->uuid('updated_by');
            $table->foreign('transaction_rate_type')->references('id')->on('transaction_rate_types');
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you provide your migration and the code you are using for validation?

Comment: Please share the contents of the `rules()` method of your request class.

Comment: Could you add this line at the beginning of your controller action: `dd($request->all());` and let us know the output?

Comment: You need to make sure you are receiving the expected values in the `$request` first

Comment: i edited and added the rule on request class and up method in migration in the quesion

Comment: In your controller method, replace `public function store(CustomRequest $request)` with `public function store(Request $request)` then add `dd($request->all())` then hit the endpoint again and then tell us what you see.

Comment: ***dd($request->all());  gives me (note that i have insert discount_in_percentage too)***  ```array:9 [
  "transaction_rate_type" => "1"
  "discount_in_percentage" => "1"
  "account_type" => "2"

]

Comment: when i replace the CustomeRequest class with Request is gives me a error error Class http\Env\Request does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I'm using regex validation, especially in special characters and numbers

```
$rules = [
        'transaction_rate_type' => ['required'],
        'discount_in_percentage' => ['regex:/^[0-9]+$/', 'between:0,99.99'],
        'account_type' => ['required'],

];
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: above answer helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

example) ?transaction_rate_type=1&discount_in_percentage=&account_type=1

'' is not 'numeric'.

```
'discount_in_percentage' => ['nullable', 'numeric', 'between:0,99.99'],
```

or

prevent sending param 'discount_in_percentage' if not input.

use JavaScript

example) ?transaction_rate_type=1&account_type=1